# UINavigationBar disappears when another view segue's to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have 5 view controllers in my app, the project starts with a `NavigationController`. Naturally when I could connect an action to "push" from view 1 to view 2, my view 2 would have a navigation bar and a back button.

So my layout is like this: 1 ViewController has 4 round rect buttons with actions to "push" to the 4 other views. Since I have 5, the fifth one is actually an additional view that I have added, and in order to reach that view you must touch a round rect button that i have placed in the 4th view that will do a "flip horizontal" to the 5th view.

Here is the problem, now my 5th view does not have a navigation bar, and when I add a round rect button on my 5th view to segue back to the 4th view, I now see that the navigation bar that once was is no longer there.

I have tried to manually add a navigation bar to view 4 & 5, I am able to do so successfully but I am unable to add "back" buttons to them by dragging them. Can someone help me fix this problem please?

Comment: Sounds like you used a modal segue to get to the 5th view, is that correct?

Comment: @SarabyteStudios Yes that is correct, it was a manual segue

Comment: In order to keep the navigation bar it needs to be presented by a push segue.

Comment: @SarabyteStudios I just tried doing it with a push segue and while it does work, it doesn't give me the look I am going for, (I am going for the flip), Since the bar does disappear and I have manually added a navigation bar, would you be able to help me add a back button? the same I would have automatically had I been using "push" all along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding a back button you can use a custom segue class. Create a new file named "flip" and make it a subclass of UIStoryBoardSegue. Once the files are created open up flip.m and paste this code above @end

```
- (void) perform {

UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
[UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:.8

                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft

                animations:^{

                    [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];

                }

                completion:NULL];

}
```

Next go to your storyboard and select the segue from the 4th view to the 5th. Set the style to custom and set the segue class to: flip

This will allow you to keep the navigation bar and the flip animation.

Comment: This works great when going from the 4th to the 5th, but when I apply the same segue type flip to go from 5th to 4th, the nav bar in the 4th disappears @SarabyteStudios

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about that. Then the best way might just be to make it a modal, add a navigation bar and a done button with an action the will close the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Embed the 5th ViewController in a navigationController In the 5th VC now there will be a navigation bar. Add a UIBarButton and link it to a method that executes the following:

```
[self.navigationController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Just for explanation, your 5th view's navigation controller (the one you embedded it in) will now be dismissed by it's `presentingViewController`

Also, the modal flip segue will actually be going to the navigation controller.

Edit/Note: When doing transitions like this I find it easier to do programmatically so you can pass anything along to your (5th) viewController no problem. In this case you would create your 5th VC then create the navigationController with the  5thVC as its root.

```
// setup of firstVC
UIViewController *firstVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstVC" bundle:nil];

// Create the navCon with firstVC as root
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];

// Set it to flip
[navCon setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

// Now present it
[self presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```